# Flutter Web View: error de autorizacion disallowed_useragent

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

Estoy practicando una app con flutter, tengo una web view donde el usuario entra a determinado sitio web y puede realizar su registro a traves del boton de google.

Pero se me presenta este problema, como podria otorgar permisos para un correcto inicio de sesion o registro con google para dichas webs?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo donde abro esa pantalla webview:

```
 Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      width: 2.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Ir al curso',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => webview(
                  namePage: widget.td.title,
                  url: 'https://www.youtube.com/')));
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Como cargas esta pantalla? Agrega el código

Comment: acabé de añadir el codigo por edicion, gracias

Comment: Revisa si tienes instalada la app Chrome en tu dispositivo, esto puede ser el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error se provoca cuando Google no reconoce el navegador, primeramente **asegura tener instalado en tu dispositivo el navegador Chrome**.

Si esto no resuelve el problema, te sugiero definir un `User-Agent` de esta forma:

```
 userAgent: "random"
```

Ejemplo:

```
body: const WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://-----------------------------------',
        userAgent: "random",
      ),
```